# Why does m_zh = zookeeper_init( m_zkUrl.c_str(), NULL, 10000, 0, NULL, 0 ) cause a memory leak?

Tags: c++, c, memory-leaks, valgrind, apache-zookeeper

I implemented one class to handle all zookeeper stuff. In connect(), I used **m_zh = zookeeper_init( m_zkUrl.c_str(), NULL, 10000, 0, NULL, 0 );** to get a zookeeper handler. In the class destructor, I used **zookeeper_close( m_zh );** to free this zookeeper handler. Why there still some memory leak? The output of valgrind is following.

**...**

==5003== 300 (60 direct, 240 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 11 of 13

==5003==    at 0x4C2CFA7: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:296)

==5003==    by 0x596A594: nss_parse_service_list (nsswitch.c:678)

==5003==    by 0x596B055: __nss_database_lookup (nsswitch.c:175)

==5003==    by 0x6028623: ???

==5003==    by 0x5923BFC: getpwuid_r@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (getXXbyYY_r.c:256)

==5003==    by 0x5946E6E: __getlogin_r_loginuid (getlogin_r.c:68)

==5003==    by 0x5946BC4: getlogin (getlogin.c:35)

==5003==    by 0x4044D4: log_env (zookeeper.c:733)

==5003==    by 0x406026: zookeeper_init (zookeeper.c:770)

==5003==    by 0x402FFC: ZKConnection::connect() (zkconnection.cpp:37)

==5003==    by 0x402962: main (test_zk.cpp:44)

**...**

```
==4624== LEAK SUMMARY:

==4624==    definitely lost: 60 bytes in 1 blocks

==4624==    indirectly lost: 240 bytes in 10 blocks

==4624==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks

==4624==    still reachable: 5,120 bytes in 2 blocks

==4624==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

Comment: Your code is pure C++ if you use the c_str() method; I would consider dropping the C tag.

Comment: because I used the zookeeper c client library..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that it is a memory leak?

Valgrind says that it's `still reachable`, which is generally [not a problem](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/faq.html#faq.deflost).

The memory is allocated within `getTSData`, whose name suggests that it's using [thread-local storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage) and whose [implementation](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/zookeeper/trunk/src/c/src/zk_log.c?view=markup) shows that it only allocates the buffer once per thread and properly registers the function freeBuffer to free this allocated memory when the thread ends.

Your code does have a memory leak (`definitely lost: 60 bytes in 1 blocks`), but I don't see anything to indicate that it's within `zookeeper_init`.

Comment: In my class, I commented all the statements except the two statements:**m_zh = zookeeper_init( m_zkUrl.c_str(), NULL, 10000, 0, NULL, 0 )** and **zookeeper_close( m_zh )**

Comment: @ChengchengPei - The Valgrind log snipped that you posted (`loss record 13 of 13`) is probably not a memory leak (because it's `still reachable`). zookeeper_init's calling calloc is probably not a memory leak, as I explained. Valgrind is saying you have a memory leak (`definitely lost: 60 bytes in 1 blocks`, `indirectly lost: 240 bytes in 10 blocks`), but it's presumably elsewhere in your code (outside of your `ZKConnection` class).

Comment: Sorry, I should posted loss record 11 0f 13. I already edited my question. But the functions, where problems are caused, are the same.

Comment: @ChengchengPei - There's nothing ZooKeeper-specific about `getlogin`. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/22932458/25507.