# Valgrind showing still reachable memory leak with getaddrinfo

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind, getaddrinfo

The following code is an excerpt of my C programm to connect to a server:

```c
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>

#define PORTNUMBER 443
#define HOSTNAME "www.google.com"

int main() {
  struct addrinfo hints, * res, * matchingIP;
  char addrstr[99];
  char port[20];
  snprintf(port, sizeof(port), "%d", PORTNUMBER); // PORTNUMBER as char*
  int sock;
  memset( & hints, 0, sizeof hints);
  hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
  hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
  hints.ai_protocol = 0;
  hints.ai_flags = AI_CANONNAME;

  int status = getaddrinfo(HOSTNAME, port, & hints, & matchingIP); // Memory Leak occurs here?
  if (status < 0) {
    perror("No IP address found.");
  }

  for (res = matchingIP; res != NULL; res = res -> ai_next) {
    sock = socket(res -> ai_family, res -> ai_socktype, res -> ai_protocol);
    if (sock < 0) {
      perror("No socket created.");
      continue;
    }

    if (connect(sock, res -> ai_addr, res -> ai_addrlen) < 0) {
      perror("Client not connected.");
      continue;
    }
    break;
  }

  if (res == NULL) {
    perror("Client could not connect.");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  inet_ntop(res -> ai_family, & ((struct sockaddr_in * ) res -> ai_addr) -> sin_addr, addrstr, sizeof addrstr);
  printf("IPv4 address: %s (%s)\n", addrstr, res -> ai_canonname);
  freeaddrinfo(matchingIP);
}
```

Now when I run valgrind, it shows there is "still reachable" memory, I've narrowed it down to the `getaddrinfo` call (the leak does not appear before). Here is the full valgrind log:

```
==566543== HEAP SUMMARY:
==566543==     in use at exit: 3,509 bytes in 8 blocks
==566543==   total heap usage: 112 allocs, 104 frees, 112,649 bytes allocated
==566543== 
==566543== 38 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 7
==566543==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==566543==    by 0x401F5DE: strdup (strdup.c:42)
==566543==    by 0x4019A91: _dl_load_cache_lookup (dl-cache.c:338)
==566543==    by 0x400A989: _dl_map_object (dl-load.c:2102)
==566543==    by 0x400F514: openaux (dl-deps.c:64)
==566543==    by 0x4A17B47: _dl_catch_exception (dl-error-skeleton.c:208)
==566543==    by 0x400F962: _dl_map_object_deps (dl-deps.c:248)
==566543==    by 0x4015DAF: dl_open_worker (dl-open.c:571)
==566543==    by 0x4A17B47: _dl_catch_exception (dl-error-skeleton.c:208)
==566543==    by 0x4015609: _dl_open (dl-open.c:837)
==566543==    by 0x4A16AE0: do_dlopen (dl-libc.c:96)
==566543==    by 0x4A17B47: _dl_catch_exception (dl-error-skeleton.c:208)
==566543== 
==566543== 38 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 2 of 7
==566543==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==566543==    by 0x400D5B7: _dl_new_object (dl-object.c:196)
==566543==    by 0x4006E96: _dl_map_object_from_fd (dl-load.c:997)
==566543==    by 0x400A61A: _dl_map_object (dl-load.c:2236)
==566543==    by 0x400F514: openaux (dl-deps.c:64)
==566543==    by 0x4A17B47: _dl_catch_exception (dl-error-skeleton.c:208)
==566543==    by 0x400F962: _dl_map_object_deps (dl-deps.c:248)
==566543==    by 0x4015DAF: dl_open_worker (dl-open.c:571)
==566543==    by 0x4A17B47: _dl_catch_exception (dl-error-skeleton.c:208)
==566543==    by 0x4015609: _dl_open (dl-open.c:837)
==566543==    by 0x4A16AE0: do_dlopen (dl-libc.c:96)
==566543==    by 0x4A17B47: _dl_catch_exception (dl-error-skeleton.c:208)
==566543== 
==566543== 45 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 3 of 7
==566543==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==566543==    by 0x401F5DE: strdup (strdup.c:42)
==566543==    by 0x4019A91: _dl_load_cache_lookup (dl-cache.c:338)
==566543==    by 0x400A989: _dl_map_object (dl-load.c:2102)
==566543==    by 0x4015D46: dl_open_worker (dl-open.c:513)
==566543==    by 0x4A17B47: _dl_catch_exception (dl-error-skeleton.c:208)
==566543==    by 0x4015609: _dl_open (dl-open.c:837)
==566543==    by 0x4A16AE0: do_dlopen (dl-libc.c:96)
==566543==    by 0x4A17B47: _dl_catch_exception (dl-error-skeleton.c:208)
==566543==    by 0x4A17C12: _dl_catch_error (dl-error-skeleton.c:227)
==566543==    by 0x4A16C14: dlerror_run (dl-libc.c:46)
==566543==    by 0x4A16C14: __libc_dlopen_mode (dl-libc.c:195)
==566543==    by 0x49FA8CB: nss_load_library (nsswitch.c:359)
==566543== 
==566543== 45 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 4 of 7
==566543==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==566543==    by 0x400D5B7: _dl_new_object (dl-object.c:196)
==566543==    by 0x4006E96: _dl_map_object_from_fd (dl-load.c:997)
==566543==    by 0x400A61A: _dl_map_object (dl-load.c:2236)
==566543==    by 0x4015D46: dl_open_worker (dl-open.c:513)
==566543==    by 0x4A17B47: _dl_catch_exception (dl-error-skeleton.c:208)
==566543==    by 0x4015609: _dl_open (dl-open.c:837)
==566543==    by 0x4A16AE0: do_dlopen (dl-libc.c:96)
==566543==    by 0x4A17B47: _dl_catch_exception (dl-error-skeleton.c:208)
==566543==    by 0x4A17C12: _dl_catch_error (dl-error-skeleton.c:227)
==566543==    by 0x4A16C14: dlerror_run (dl-libc.c:46)
==566543==    by 0x4A16C14: __libc_dlopen_mode (dl-libc.c:195)
==566543==    by 0x49FA8CB: nss_load_library (nsswitch.c:359)
==566543== 
==566543== 936 bytes in 2 blocks are still reachable in loss record 5 of 7
==566543==    at 0x483DD99: calloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==566543==    by 0x401331C: _dl_check_map_versions (dl-version.c:274)
==566543==    by 0x40160FC: dl_open_worker (dl-open.c:577)
==566543==    by 0x4A17B47: _dl_catch_exception (dl-error-skeleton.c:208)
==566543==    by 0x4015609: _dl_open (dl-open.c:837)
==566543==    by 0x4A16AE0: do_dlopen (dl-libc.c:96)
==566543==    by 0x4A17B47: _dl_catch_exception (dl-error-skeleton.c:208)
==566543==    by 0x4A17C12: _dl_catch_error (dl-error-skeleton.c:227)
==566543==    by 0x4A16C14: dlerror_run (dl-libc.c:46)
==566543==    by 0x4A16C14: __libc_dlopen_mode (dl-libc.c:195)
==566543==    by 0x49FA8CB: nss_load_library (nsswitch.c:359)
==566543==    by 0x49FB178: __nss_lookup_function (nsswitch.c:467)
==566543==    by 0x49BB4BE: gaih_inet.constprop.0 (getaddrinfo.c:800)
==566543== 
==566543== 1,200 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 6 of 7
==566543==    at 0x483DD99: calloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==566543==    by 0x400D283: _dl_new_object (dl-object.c:89)
==566543==    by 0x4006E96: _dl_map_object_from_fd (dl-load.c:997)
==566543==    by 0x400A61A: _dl_map_object (dl-load.c:2236)
==566543==    by 0x400F514: openaux (dl-deps.c:64)
==566543==    by 0x4A17B47: _dl_catch_exception (dl-error-skeleton.c:208)
==566543==    by 0x400F962: _dl_map_object_deps (dl-deps.c:248)
==566543==    by 0x4015DAF: dl_open_worker (dl-open.c:571)
==566543==    by 0x4A17B47: _dl_catch_exception (dl-error-skeleton.c:208)
==566543==    by 0x4015609: _dl_open (dl-open.c:837)
==566543==    by 0x4A16AE0: do_dlopen (dl-libc.c:96)
==566543==    by 0x4A17B47: _dl_catch_exception (dl-error-skeleton.c:208)
==566543== 
==566543== 1,207 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 7 of 7
==566543==    at 0x483DD99: calloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==566543==    by 0x400D283: _dl_new_object (dl-object.c:89)
==566543==    by 0x4006E96: _dl_map_object_from_fd (dl-load.c:997)
==566543==    by 0x400A61A: _dl_map_object (dl-load.c:2236)
==566543==    by 0x4015D46: dl_open_worker (dl-open.c:513)
==566543==    by 0x4A17B47: _dl_catch_exception (dl-error-skeleton.c:208)
==566543==    by 0x4015609: _dl_open (dl-open.c:837)
==566543==    by 0x4A16AE0: do_dlopen (dl-libc.c:96)
==566543==    by 0x4A17B47: _dl_catch_exception (dl-error-skeleton.c:208)
==566543==    by 0x4A17C12: _dl_catch_error (dl-error-skeleton.c:227)
==566543==    by 0x4A16C14: dlerror_run (dl-libc.c:46)
==566543==    by 0x4A16C14: __libc_dlopen_mode (dl-libc.c:195)
==566543==    by 0x49FA8CB: nss_load_library (nsswitch.c:359)
==566543== 
==566543== LEAK SUMMARY:
==566543==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==566543==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==566543==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==566543==    still reachable: 3,509 bytes in 8 blocks
==566543==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==566543== 
==566543== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

I've read online several times that while "still reachable" memory leaks are memory leaks, they are not ones I should worry about. Sadly for me, it is a formal requirement that valgrind reports absolutely no memory leaks, including still reachable. Is there any chance I am able to fix it or is it the fault of the library? If the latter - what are suitable alternatives?
As far as I am are the host runs using IPv6 - perhaps that's relevant.

Edit: The project is compiled with the `-std=c99` flag and defines the posix C source as `#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L`. The valgrind flags are `valgrind --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all --trace-children=yes --log-file=log.txt --track-origins=yes -s` and I'm developing on Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS

Another edit: [Minimal reproducible example](https://github.com/JonathanTheZero/C-valgrind-memory-leak)

Comment: I can informally confirm that `getaddrinfo()` is a function, which - at least in some versions of the library - allocates heap memory that you as the client cannot explicitly free.

Comment: *Sadly for me, it is a formal requirement that valgrind reports absolutely no memory leaks, including still reachable.* Well, whoever wrote that formal requirement now should file a bug report on glibc, because when you look at that stack trace, that's glibc dynamically loading a shared object with `nss_load_library()`.  If I were them, I wouldn't hold my breath waiting for glibc to fix it.  Heck, I wouldn't hold my breath waiting for glibc to even accept it as a bug.

Comment: There is an option to Valgrind to increase the depth of the stack trace-back printout.  The depth you are using is 12 (the default IIRC).  If you increase that, you should get to a point that verifies `getaddrinfo()` as the culprit.  It looks like the problem could be in the `dl_open()` code used to load supporting code for `getaddrinfo()` rather than the function itself.  Maybe unloading the library would help if you can reliably identify which library or libraries are loaded.

Comment: This is almost identical to [**Memory leaks observed in getgrnam and getgrnam_r in linux**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73976258/memory-leaks-observed-in-getgrnam-and-getgrnam-r-in-linux)

Comment: This is not normal. Can you share more information about your program and environment? Perhaps a full program, compiler version, and, most importantly, the operating system you are on (so we can verify libc version, etc).

Comment: @FelipeFR This is quite normal for glibc.

Comment: "*I've read online several times that while 'still reachable' memory leaks are memory leaks, they are not ones I should worry about.*" -- I guess that's one view, but I claim that "still reachable" issues *do not* represent leaks.  At no point during the lifetime of the allocated object is it ever inaccessible.  That may be small comfort if the requirement is going to be interpreted differently, but it might be worthwhile to try to make that argument.

Comment: @JohnBollinger That's supported by the stack trace entries such as `_dl_load_cache_lookup (dl-cache.c:338)`.  glibc is *caching* data.  There probably isn't even any way to make glibc release it.

Comment: Note also that "*Valgrind reports* no memory leaks" is not at all the same thing as "*there are* no memory leaks".  Valgrind provides for "suppression" files that instruct it not to report on well-known issues that (someone decided) do not constitute a problem in practice.  It ships with a bunch of these.  You could always prepare your own, and it might be easier to get such a suppression file added to the standard set than to get Glibc modified to not trigger Valgrind's message.

Comment: @Zer0 Could you compile with `-ggdb -fsanitize=address,undefined,leak` and run the program normally (not via `valgrind`) and provide the output from that too?

Comment: @AndrewHenle "There probably isn't even any way to make glibc release it.". Is that a Dunning-Kruger 'probably' given that clearly you know little about either GNU libc or Valgrind in this respect?

Comment: @JohnBollinger Generally agreed but Valgrind has very few leak suppressions. It's not really our job to cover up GNU libc bugs.

Comment: @PaulFloyd Read the [bug's history](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_activity.cgi?id=28808)  it's been completely ignored for two years.  Your faith in glibc is totes adorbs.

Comment: @PaulFloyd, it's open to interpretation whether this should be considered a bug at all.  In fact, I'd argue that the answer to that would be a clear "NO" if Valgrind did not report the issue.  That Valgrind has achieved such status that ignorant managers make blanket rules such as "all issues reported by Valgrind must be resolved" actually *does* put some responsibility on you and the rest of the Valgrind team to at least give careful consideration to suppressing harmless Glibc issues, especially those that users have no good way to work around anyway.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I have no illusions. If you want it fixed, submit a patch to libc or get something like a RedHat support contract.

Answer (score 1):

My opinion is that this is most likely a GNU libc bug.

Oh look.

[Valgrind saying it's a GNU libc bug](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=448991)

[GNU libc bug](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=28808)

GNU libc includes a cleanup function, `__libc_freeres()` that gets called by Valgrind **upon a clean exit**. It sounds like someone added some dynamic loading and there's missing cleanup of the dynamic loading name cache from __libc_freeres.

I could add that to the Valgrind default supressions. That would only be the last resort if the GNU libc devs refuse to fix the issue. The above bug has been open for getting on for 2 years so it's not looking very optimistic.

> Sadly for me, it is a formal requirement that valgrind reports absolutely no memory leaks, including still reachable.

If the goal there is to improve your software quality that's a good thing. But if the goal is only to give the appearance of quality and to enable the suits to make powerpoint presentatons with a page showing zero leaks then that's a bad thing. That's a slippery slope that leads to huge suppression files that risk hiding genuine issues.

Having said that, personally I would add a suppression for this.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any chance I am able to fix it or is it the fault of the
> library?

It's not really a *fault*, but as you noted (and was also mentioned in the comments) `libc` decided it needs to bind to `libnss`. There are at least a couple of ways to confirm that:

1. Run your program with `LD_DEBUG=bindings` (e.g., `LD_DEBUG=bindings ./program`)
2. Add a `getchar()` to pause your program before exiting and examine `/proc/<pid>/maps`.

Unfortunatelly, there's no reliable or portable way to `dl_close()` that I'm aware of.

> If the latter - what are suitable alternatives?

The best alternative is to provide `valgrind` with a *suppressions file* which will make it ignore specific allocations/leaks/reachable blocks.

You can generate one specifically for this case by running `valgrind` as you did but adding the option `--gen-suppressions=yes`.

Answer (score 0):

And going through your options

> valgrind --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all --trace-children=yes --log-file=log.txt --track-origins=yes -s

Does your executable spawn child processes? If not you don't need `--trace-children=yes`. On the other hand if you do spawn and need `--trace-children=yes` then you should by using the pid in the log file name, such as `--log-file=log.%p,txt` where %p will be replaced by the PID. If you don't do that then the child log files will overwrite parent ones.

I don't recommend using `--track-origins=yes` until after you have found errors. It causes a fairly significant slowdown. If you're OK with that overhead then the advantage is that it will have more info to start with.

`-s` if you are really serious then you will check that any suppressions that you have added are still in use and remove them when they are no longer used.

Comment: The original program does spawn children but the valgrind logfile is divided into several section, each covering a different process. I fear I'll need to go wth the suppression files. I'm fairly sure this happens when using `getaddrinfo` with IPv6 as it does not occur when using an IPv4 address